# My First Tomcat Servlet

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I seem to be having trouble with Tomcat servlets and even setting up my own. I am using Windows Vista x64 bit. I CAN connect and see the servlet examples. I just don't know how to go about creating my own.

Can anyone pinpoint to me a guide on "my first servlet" with a step-by-step instructions on how-to?

Thanks.

[Do not close this as there is clearly a question here.]

Comment: Someone has already answered that in your duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2262981/my-first-tomcat-servlet/2263002#2263002

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is Sun's [Instant Tutorial](http://java.sun.com/products/servlet/articles/tutorial/) of use ?

Or maybe [this tutorial](http://www.jsptube.com/servlet-tutorials/simple-servlet-example.html), which covers not only the coding (normally straightforward) but also the construction of the `web.xml` and the deployment, which can cause a lot of grief to the uninitiated.

Answer (score 1):

Start my modifying an existing servlet, as suggested [previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2262981/my-first-tomcat-servlet/2263002#2263002). Then add a new servlet to an existing web application, such as Tomcat's `examples`. Then look at one of the numerous tutorials on the web. I like Marty Hall's original [*Servlets and JavaServer Pages (JSP) 1.0: A Tutorial*](http://www.apl.jhu.edu/~hall/java/Servlet-Tutorial/). Although it's now outdated, it is also very methodical.

Answer (score 0):

[There](http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=servlet+tutorial) [are](http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=tomcat+tutorial) [several](http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=eclipse+tutorial) [video](http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=jsp+servlet+tutorial) [tutorials](http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=servlet+tomcat+tutorial) [at](http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=jsp+servlet+tomcat+tutorial) [Youtube](http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=jsp+servlet+eclipse+tomcat+tutorial).

Particularly [this one](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EOkN5IPoJVs) is pretty good to get started. You only need to have [JDK6 downloaded and installed](http://java.sun.com/javase/downloads/widget/jdk6.jsp) and [Eclipse for Java EE developers](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) and [Apache Tomcat 6.0](http://tomcat.apache.org/download-60.cgi) downloaded and unzipped.

Comment: No? Eclipse is written in Java. Java is platform independent. It's a matter of having the right JVM. Sure the problem lies somewhere else :)